# Overloading operator = error

Tags: c++, templates, stack

Im trying to create a stack but im receiving errors with overloading my = operator.
The stack is of type template. Heres the code

```
template <typename T>
T& ::stack& operator =(const stack& other)
{
    if (this == &other) return *this;

    copy(other.stack1[0], other.stack1[other.size], stack1[0]);
    return *this;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please post the error you are having. Now, I would say that returning `*this` is not correct since `this` is already a pointer.

Comment: What is `T&::stack&`?

Comment: @JaviV But the operator does not, and should not, return a pointer.

Comment: @juanchopanza Oops you are completely right, I just got my mind switched off for a few seconds hehe.

Comment: @Nicknack: What is the implementation of the `stack`? How are you holding the data?

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below signature

```
template <typename T>
stack<T>& stack<T>:: operator =(const stack<T>& other)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
template <typename T>
stack<T>& stack<T>::operator =(const stack& other)
{
    if (this == &other) return *this;

    copy(other.stack1[0], other.stack1[other.size], stack1[0]);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a gem. If possible would you mind explaining why you use stack<T>& stack<T> and then return a pointer? Thanks

Comment: @Nicknack, you are welcome. The return value is `*this`, which is a reference to an object. `this` would be a pointer.

Comment: @Nicknack: `stack` is a template, not a type. You cannot declare a function to return a *template*. When you write `stack<T>` you are naming a *type* (the type resulting from specializing the `stack` template with the type argument `T`). The confusion might come from the fact that when lookup is done inside the context of the template class there is an injected name `stack` that really means `stack<T>`. Lookup for the argument of the member function calls into this category as it is done inside the class and thus `const stack&` really means `const stack<T>&` there

Answer (score 0):

Apart from incorrect declaration of the operator it seems that there is also incorrect usage of standard algorithm copy within the body of the operator provided that stack1 is an array

I can only suppose that the operator should look as

```
template <typename T>
stack<T> & stack<T>::operator =( const stack<T> &other )
{
    if ( this == &other ) return *this;

    this->size = other.size; 
    copy( other.stack1, other.stack1 + other.size, this->stack1 );

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what the error was with using copy?

Comment: @Nicknack You did not show the class definition so I can only suppose that stack1 is an array. If it is indeed an array then you are coping it incorrectly. In my post there is written how the array shall be copied.

Comment: lol... *incorrect declaration of the operator* followed by the fix containing `stack<T>:perator` :-)